# How do I split data from strings and put them into pre-defined categories?

Tags: python

I am trying to split the following sentences which are stored in an array, into categories. The categories are line number, stations, type of closure, and dates, as all subway closure announcements I'm scraping are in this format.

```
"Line 1: Finch to Sheppard-Yonge nightly early closures March 23 to 26 - CANCELLED"
"Line 1: Lawrence to St Clair weekend closure Sunday, March 29 - REVISED"
"Line 1: Sheppard-Yonge to St Clair nightly early closures March 30 to April 2 - REVISED"9
```

For example:

```
Line = {0:"Line 1", 1:"Line 1", 2:"Line 1"}
Stations = {0: "Finch to Sheppard-Yonge", 1:"Lawrence to St Clair", 2:"Sheppard-Yonge to St Clair"}
```

I've created some pretty complicated for loops to do this, however, they're pretty buggy, and require different code logic for every category. Below is an example of how I extracted the 'type of closure' from the above sentences, I made an assumption that there are 3 closure types which are stored in the `closure_types` array:

```
closure_types = ["nightly early closures","single day closure","weekend closure"]
closure_types_split = []
for closure_type in closure_types:
    split_closure_type_a = closure_type.split()
    closure_types_split.append(split_closure_type_a)


closure_type_categorized = []
for i in range(len(split_closures)): 
    for ins in range(len(closure_types_split)):
        try:
            first_word_in_closure_types_split = closure_types_split[ins][0]
            first_word = split_closures[i].index(str(first_word_in_closure_types_split))
            if split_closures[i][first_word] == 'nightly':
                last_word = first_word + 3
                closure_type_categorized.append(split_closures[i][first_word:last_word])
            elif split_closures[i][first_word] == 'single':
                last_word = first_word + 2
                closure_type_categorized.append(split_closures[i][first_word:last_word])
            elif split_closures[i][first_word] == 'weekend':
                last_word = first_word + 2
                closure_type_categorized.append(split_closures[i][first_word:last_word])
        except:
            pass
```

My question is if there is an easier way to do what I'm trying to do? Or are there any python libraries designed to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Look for information on simple parsers and natural language systems.  It appears that your grammar for this is relatively restricted, such that a simple parser would do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled using regular expressions

```
import re

# note: spaces in the names must use `\s` (see St Clair), 
# because the re pattern uses verbose mode.
stations = '|'.join(line.strip() for line in 
    r"""
    Finch
    Lawrence
    Sheppard-Yonge
    St\sClair
    """.strip().splitlines())

# The re pattern is a raw f-string so the {stations} can be inserted.
pattern = rf"""(?ix)
    Line\s+(?P<line>\d+):
    \s*
    (?P<where>(?:{stations})(?:\s*to\s*(?:{stations}))*)    # one or more stations separated by 'to'
    \s*
    (?P<what>(?:\w*\s+)*?closures?)                         # phrase ending with closure or closures
    \s*
    (?P<when>[^-]*)                                         # everything up to a '-'
    \s*
    (?:-\s* (?P<note>.*))?                                  # if there is a '-' everything after it
    """

template = re.compile(pattern)
```

Using it on the testcases:

```
testcases = [
    "Line 1: Finch to Sheppard-Yonge nightly early closures March 23 to 26 - CANCELLED",
    "Line 1: Lawrence to St Clair weekend closure Sunday, March 29 - REVISED",
    "Line 1: Sheppard-Yonge to St Clair nightly early closures March 30 to April 2 - REVISED",
]

for test in testcases:
    mo = template.search(test)
    print(mo.groupdict())
```

Prints:

```
{'line': '1', 'where': 'Finch to Sheppard-Yonge', 'what': 'nightly early closures', 'when': 'March 23 to 26 ', 'note': 'CANCELLED'}
{'line': '1', 'where': 'Lawrence to St Clair', 'what': 'weekend closure', 'when': 'Sunday, March 29 ', 'note': 'REVISED'}
{'line': '1', 'where': 'Sheppard-Yonge to St Clair', 'what': 'nightly early closures', 'when': 'March 30 to April 2 ', 'note': 'REVISED'}
```

For more complicated parsing problems I like the TatSu library.

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar appears quite straightforward.  For instance:
"Line 1: Finch to Sheppard-Yonge nightly early closures March 23 to 26 - CANCELLED"
"Line 1: Lawrence to St Clair weekend closure Sunday, March 29 - REVISED"
"Line 1: Sheppard-Yonge to St Clair nightly early closures March 30 to April 2 - REVISED"

```
NOTICE => LINE_FIELD STATIONS CLOSURE DATES "-" STATUS
LINE_FIELD => "Line " integer ":"
STATIONS => string {"to" string}
CLOSURE => string ["closure" | "closures"] string
DATES => DATE_1 {to DATE_2}
DATE_1 => month integer
DATE_2 => {month} integer
STATUS => ["CANCELLED" | "REVISED"]
```

I leave finishing the grammar to you.  The critical parsing points at the top level are to find the "closure" word to extract the CLOSURE phrase, and find the hyphen to separate the last phrases.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: This is great and helpful, but I've got the grammar part down. My primary issue is finding the right module/library to code it to reap the results. Your comment under my post did set me on a good path and I found that the regex module might help however I am still exploring it and other alternatives.